# how can I call a method from another class?

Tags: c++, object

I have 3 files pos.h pos.cpp and main.cpp .... I am trying to call a function from pos.cpp in the main class for instance :

pos.h file

```
class pos {
   public:
   pos(); //defualut constructor 
int open_port();
}
```

pos.cpp

```
#include "pos.h"
int Open_port()    {
//do stuff here
    return 0;
    }
```

class main.cpp

```
#include "pos.h"
int main(int argc , char** argv) {
pos pos1;
pos1::Open_port();
}
```

Problem is I always get that pos1 is not a class or namespace I am compining as follows 
g++ mainpos.cpp pos.cpp pos.h  -o position -lpthread
Any thoughts ?

Comment: You want `pos1.open_port();` instead of accessing it via :: in your `main` function. And in pos.cpp, you need `pos::open_port` as the function name, not `Open_port` (case matters)

Answer (score 2):

You seems to have several issues in the code:

```
int open_port();
```

is a member function of `pos`. However, when you define it, you are not using `::` operator and the function name is changed.

Try:

```
 int pos::open_port()
 {      ///^^pay attention to typos
     //do stuff here
     return 0;
 }
```

Then inside `main`. you can do:

```
 pos pos1;
 pos1.open_port();
```

If you really mean `Open_port()`, which is not a member of the class, then you need to add function declaration into the proper header files and use it properly, but that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

You've several problems, most of them related to fundamental syntax:

1. Case matters. `open_port` and `Open_port` are two completely different things
2. You're not actually defining the method of the class `pos`, you're making a new function

   ```
   int Open_port()    {
   ```

   needs to be

   ```
   int pos::open_port()    {
   ```
3. You're trying to invoke a non-static method statically. You need to create an instance of `pos`, (which you've done, `pos1`) and invoke `open_port` on it via `pos1.open_port()`. You cannot call `pos::open_port` directly, unless you declare the method `static`.
4. A final problem would be that you've declared but not defined the default constructor for your class. You  need to provide a method body for `pos::pos()`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have two problems with your code. In the `cpp` file you need to use the scope for that function, so you need to have:

`int pos::Open_port()`

Also, you need to ensure that `open_port` and `Open_port` are spelled and capitalized the same.

Last thing, if you want to call `open_port` like that, you'll need to decare the function as `static` in the class def'n.